# How to debug MAC OSX utun driver/routing decisions?

Tags: ichat

I want to debug why video/audio of iChat/jabber is sent from the physical interface and not from utun0 interface. How to debug MAC OSX utun driver or routing decision?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use tcpdump -- try dumping the default route interface and the utun interface and see which one shows packets.